# How to disable the button if some input field is not filled?

Tags: dojo

IBM web experience factory uses dojo library, I am wondering if the I set `<input type="text" name="usrname" required>` in the consumer model, does the button still work if the input is not filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Methods) has a method called `checkValidity()` which you can use.

So, in your case, you could use the `:input` selector with `dojo/query` to query all input elements inside a form (includes buttons, checkboxes, textfields, text areas and select boxes) and then use the `onChange` event to check if the form is valid and change the buttons `disabled` attribute.

For example:

```js
query("[name=myForm] :input").on("change", function(evt) {
    var isInvalid = !evt.target.form.checkValidity();
    query("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", isInvalid);
});
```

Now all you need to do is to make sure that your button is initially disabled/enabled depending on the initial state of the form.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8L6j77g/